# 500 Internal error - Timeout expired

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, iis, sql, internal-server-error

I am getting "500 Internal Server" error while accessing my webapplication in SharePoint 2010.  After some tracing I found that the actual error is :

> "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled 
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached"

After I perform IIS Reset everything works fine but only for few minutes. I have already tried following:
increase the executionTimeout in web.config to 3600

- edit all custom code to have dispose
- change the Idle Time-out in  IIS
- Change the timeout value to 90 in SharePoint configuration DB
  connection string

This error has recently occurred, can any one suggest what possibly could be done here.

Comment: Did you tried restarting the Application pool and Stopping unnecessary pool from running?

Comment: What about server resources? Memory, free space, cpu?

Comment: 98% usage of memory of 32 GB

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if perform IIS reset then it work fine for couple of min/hour then goes down. this make sense as 98% usage of memory of 32 GB is alot, Couple of things to check.

- why Memory usage is too high, How many App pool running on the server.
- Try to stop unused App Pool and Unwanted services from SharePoint
- If you have customization on your site then make sure no memory leaks in it.
- check the Search service, if that is consuming all resources.
- check the App Pool connection setting.
- Check the Logs for more clue.

.